# Is there a way to build selective files in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, build

Is there any way that I can select some files only build selective files and make the build ignore some files in a project?

What compiler flags or Xcode options do I need to use?

Comment: Please do not downvote, I was just curious to see if this was possible, or at least try to explain to me why this question is worth a downvote. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "only build selective files", that doesn't make sense to me

Comment: There are certain files that I have that have some errors, I want to keep them in my project, while ignoring them temporarily

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Xcode, show the project navigator (Cmd-1), click the file you want to remove from the current build. Show the file inspector (Cmd-Opt-1), locate "**Target Membership**" pane and uncheck the current target. Just check it to add it back.

You can do the same in the target "Compile Sources" phase but you'll need more clicks and if you have a few dozen files you'll need to search it in the list.

The fastest way to stop building temporarily a few lines that you know are wrong or incomplete is to wrap them with

```
#if 0
// code you want to skip
#endif
```

Also, if you want to run some experiments you can add a **new target** that includes those experimental files and add an scheme to build the experiment.

It would be much better if you use `git` and create an experimental branch, but that's a different story.

Answer (score 3):

In the project settings, in Build Settings you can add and remove individual files. However, there is no way to only build some files and not others; you are building all the files in the project.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad, I hope they introduce in the new XCode

Comment: Why would they?  How is it different from removing it from the build settings?  You can even do it in the property inspector (under target membership) so it is basically the same functionality you are describing.

Comment: The "you are building all the files in the project." is wrong. There are a lot of build rules, settings, config files, etc. that will determine which files will be built.